# Is there a way to get the data by day name in entityframework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.1

**I am trying to write code to get news on there publishing date and day,,,,,like**

```
             ViewBag.LatestNews = db.News
            .Where(ve => ve.PublishingDate >= DateTime.Now 
            && ve.IsActive == true);
```

**The output i get is correct according to requirement....
I need to filter publishing date on the DayOfWeek lets say "Sunday"...
How to write parameter that takes the day number and filter the result.
Any one help please.... 
Thanks for you time**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
ViewBag.LatestNews = db.News
                       .Where(ve => (int)ve.PublishingDate.DayOfWeek == 7 
                                       && ve.IsActive == true);
```

Or:-

```
ViewBag.LatestNews = db.News
                       .Where(ve => ve.PublishingDate.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday" 
                                       && ve.IsActive == true);
```

**Edit:**
You can use [SqlFunctions.DatePart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487171.aspx) method for linq to entity:-

```
ViewBag.LatestNews = db.News
             .Where(ve => SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw", ve.PublishingDate) == "Sunday" 
                          && ve.IsActive == true);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,,,,vs throughs the same error "Day of week is not supported in LINQ to entities",,,,

Comment: Kind of correct, but DayOfWeek and especially "Sunday" only works when running under a CultureInfo where Sunday actually is day 7, and spelled "Sunday".

Comment: thanks again,so what should be the solution,can you please help

Comment: your effort is much appreciated, i am recreating code accordingly